# Display date in local format but force time in 24-hour format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime-format

So in one instance I've decorated a nullable DateTime with

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}")]
```

and in another, an interpolated string

```
$"{theDateTimeObject:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}"
```

I want to display the date in the local format (so MM/dd/yyyy for the U.S.) but always display the time in 24-hour format, regardless of any OS settings or otherwise.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: So... in US you want to use `MM/dd/yyyy` and in the U.K use `dd/MM/yyyy`, but in both you want `HH:mm:ss`, is that correct?

Comment: DateTime has no format, it's a binary value. Fromats apply only when it's converted to a string, or a string gets parsed into a DateTime. So what's the problem? Didn't the interpolated string return what you expect?

Comment: BTW `HH` is 24-hour. If you want the *local* format to be used, just don't specify any format. Local is the default. The problem with web application is what local means - the server's local, the end user's local? Perhaps the question should be `How can I control a request's locale?`

Comment: I don't think you can do this in one format string. You can do it in two: `$"{theDateTimeObject:d} {theDateTimeObject:HH:mm:ss}"`. But it seems like a better idea to either fully respect the local settings instead of cobbling together your own hybrid format, or else set a localized format for the whole application (possibly programmatically, detected based on settings) without repeating that in custom strings or attributes.

Comment: ASP.NET uses locale autodetection to detect the *end user's* locale based on the browser's Preferred Language settings. That can be disabled. The locale can be configured at the application level in web.config or at the page/view level with keywords. Finally, a request filter could set the request locale using eg a user's preferences

Comment: @ZoharPeled exactly

Comment: @JeroenMostert not with one format string but with one instance of the `DateTimeFormatInfo` class it is possible.... but then again, you wouldn't be able to use that as a value of an attribute or as an interpolated string - it will only work with `DateTime.ToString(IFormatProvider);`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to display a string property instead of your actual DateTime value.
Here's an example:

```
private DateTime _actualDateTime;

public string DateTimeForDisplay
{
    get 
    {
        return _actualDateTime.ToString("d") +" "+ _actualDateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    }
}
```